# Read XElement from XmlReader

Tags: .net, xmpp, xmlreader

I'm playing around with parsing an XMPP XML stream. The tricky thing about the XML stream is that the start tag does not get closed until the end of the session, i.e. a complete DOM is never received.

```
<stream:stream>
    <features>
       <starttls />
    </features>
    ....
    network session persists for arbitrary time
    ....
 </stream:stream>
```

I need to read the XML elements from the stream without caring that the root element has not been closed.

Ideally this would work but it doesn't and I'm assuming it's because the reader is waiting for the root element to be closed.

```
XElement someElement = XNode.ReadFrom(xmlReader) as XElement;
```

The code below (which I borrowed from [Jacob Reimers](http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2009/10/24/starting-xmpp-with-net.aspx)) does work but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way that doesn't involve creating a new XmlReader and doing the string parsing.

```
 XmlReader stanzaReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree();
 stanzaReader.MoveToContent();
 string outerStanza = stanzaReader.ReadOuterXml();
 stanzaReader.Close();
 XElement someElement = XElement.Parse(outerStanza);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't need to work with the strings; you *should* be able to use [`XElement.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355742.aspx) on the subtree:

```
XElement someElement;
using(XmlReader stanzaReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree()) {
    someElement = XElement.Load(stanzaReader);
}
```

And note that this isn't really a "new" xml-reader - it is heavily tied to the outer reader (but constrained to a set of nodes).

Comment: Given your example I can't see why XmlReader stanzaReader = XElement.Load(xmlReader.ReadSubtree()) wouldn't do the job. I'll still have the xmlReader in a using block and that will take care of any cleanup.

Comment: @sipwiz - in that particular case you'd probably get away with it; I'm just deeply ingrained: dispose *every* `IDisposable`, promptly. `stanzaReader` is a different object, ultimately.

Comment: Earlier versions of .net's pull parser would wait for 4kB at a time to buffer.  That is why I ended up porting James Clark's XP parser from Java to C# for jabber-net.