# How to use xmlreader to parse this document?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

this is the document i want to parse

```
<item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">report_id</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2467</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">vendor_hi</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">01.01</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">area_nm</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">MALAYSIA MOBILE DIGI</value>
   </item>
</item>
<item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">report_id</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2467</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">vendor_hi</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">01.07</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <key xsi:type="xsd:string">area_nm</key>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">MALAYSIA MOBILE MAXIS</value>
   </item>
</item>
```

above is just apart of the whole document , total of items is about 3000s , if i use such code to parse

```
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(rd.BaseStream);
```

when it execute to this line

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(rd.BaseStream);
```

the speed is too slow , so i want to use xmlreader to parse , my purpose is : first loop all node of

```
<item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
```

and define three variable , say they are

```
string strRptID;
string strVendor;
string strArea;
```

then , loop every sub node "item" , and see if it has a sub node name is "key"

if exist and "key" 's value is "report_id", then set strRptID equal sub node "value" 's value

in first item 's  case is 2467

if exist and "key" 's value is "vendor_hi", then set strVendor equal sub node "value" 's value

in this case is 01.01.

if exist and "key" 's value is "area_nm", then set strArea equal sub node "value" 's value

in first item 's case is MALAYSIA MOBILE MAXIS.

then loop another

and do the same.

please help to tell me how to do this using xmlreader .

PS:

```
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(rd.BaseStream);               //breakpoint this line
```

hera request is  a HttpWebRequest ,  and i  add a breakpoint at

```
           XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(rd.BaseStream);
```

when execute to there , it does not return for almost 5Mins , i am not sure at that time , whether

the download has finished ?  i think download is happen on

```
 request.GetResponse()
```

if i am wrong , please correct me.

Comment: What do you mean "too slow" and why do you think that XmlReader will finish faster? Are you sure it's not the download delay you are measuring? Do you experience delay when loading from a local file?

Comment: what (using `XmlReader`) have you tried? Also: have you profiled using `XmlSerializer` to throw it into a simple object-model that exposes the `key`/`value` pairs and parsing from there? Have you profiled using `XElement` ? (`XmlReader` is... kinda hard to get 100% right; almost anything would be preferable to using that directly)

Comment: why i said xdocument is slow please see my edit

Comment: You are measuring download time.

Comment: To answer your question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184194/read-xelement-from-xmlreader

Answer (score 0):

What you are measuring is the time it takes to download the file, not the time needed by XDocument to parse it. Using XmlReader will take the exact same time (±a few seconds if any), because XmlReader will have to wait the same time to download the file.

GetResponse does **not** download the entire response. Data is pulled from the server whenever you read from the response stream. That's just the way web servers work when you download large amounts of data: they return a response that says everything was OK and allow you to <s>open a stream and</s> start reading the response from the response stream. If you close the stream before you reach the end, the server simply stops sending data.

Comment: Surely there is a correction needed here - the stream (tcp socket) is already open when you get the `OK` response header but it is stalled - no reads are occuring. The client does not request a new stream (as may have to with FTP). A minor difference but we dont want to confuse the issue.

Comment: Oops. Not a minor difference. Forgetting to dispose the request WILL leave the stream open until GC kicks in. If you try to open more than two connections to the same server you'll get blocked and never know why

Comment: thank you for your reply , then could you tell me why the download spend too much times, if i send same request on same client machine but using soapUI, it will return much faster than my code .