# XmlReader skipping adjoined elements

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Whilst trying to minimise the memory footprint of an XML parsing program, specifically avoiding the loading hundreds of megabytes using `XElement.Load()`, I came across articles suggesting using the older `XmlReader` [e.g. here](https://orderofcode.com/2016/05/31/reading-big-xmls-in-net/).

I need to internally reconstruct each major element as an `XElement` to avoid major refactoring.  However, I discovered that if my source elements are directly adjoining, this approach skips every 2nd element.

I've torn down the problem to this unit-test (MSTest2 with FluentAssertions):

```cs
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("<data><entry>1</entry><entry>2</entry><entry>3</entry><entry>4</entry></data>")]
[DataRow("<data><entry>1</entry> <entry>2</entry> <entry>3</entry> <entry>4</entry></data>")]
public void XmlReaderCount(string input)
{
    var sr = new StringReader(input);
    var xml = XmlReader.Create(sr);
    xml.MoveToContent();

    var data = new List<string>();
    while (xml.Read())
    {
        if (xml.LocalName == "entry" && xml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            var element = (XElement)System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom(xml);
            data.Add(element.Value);
        }
    }

    data.Should()
        .HaveCount(4);
}
```

The first (data-driven) test fails with:

> Expected collection to contain 4 item(s), but found 2.

As it puts 1 and 3 into the data collection.  It does loop 4 times, but every other element has an `xml.NodeType` of `Text`, not `Element`.  The second test (with spaces between the `</entry>` and `<entry>` passes by processing all 4.

In my real world example, I can't easily change the source. I do already have a solution, inspired by [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184194/read-xelement-from-xmlreader) so I can do the following, but it seems strange - is something wrong?

```cs
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("<data><entry>1</entry><entry>2</entry><entry>3</entry><entry>4</entry></data>")]
[DataRow("<data><entry>1</entry> <entry>2</entry> <entry>3</entry> <entry>4</entry></data>")]
public void XmlReaderCountSubtree(string input)
{
    var data = new List<string>();

    var sr = new StringReader(input);
    var xml = XmlReader.Create(sr);
    xml.MoveToContent();

    while (xml.Read())
    {
        if (xml.LocalName == "entry" && xml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            using (var subtree = xml.ReadSubtree())
            {
                subtree.MoveToContent();
                var content = subtree.ReadOuterXml();
                var element = XElement.Parse(content);
                data.Add(element.Value);
            }
         }
     }

     data.Should()
         .HaveCount(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ReadFrom(xml)` , the state of xml is changed. Its cursor is moved forward to the next element. Your code then moves on to `while (xml.Read())` and so ignores that new element completely.

With the second data set, the ignored (and uninspected) elements are the whitespace nodes so you get away with it. But basically, you reading algorithm is wrong.

A fix for your first approach, not pretty but it works:

```
xml.Read();
while (! xml.EOF)
{
    if (xml.LocalName == "entry" && xml.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        //using (var subtree = xml.ReadSubtree())
        {                    
            var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xml);
            data.Add(element.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xml.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  So doing something similar to yours with the `while(!xml.EOF)`, inside the if condition I will call `continue` and otherwise (not needing the else) I do `xml.Read()`.